# How to stop this text from going off the screen?

Tags: tumblr

I'm having this presentation issue with [Solstice](http://www.tumblr.com/theme/5112) theme. Could someone point me towards a solution, short of changing the theme?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to Advanced tab and added this under *Add custom CSS* section:

```
pre {
 overflow: auto;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You are using `<pre>` tags when you should be using `<code>` tags

Pre retains the format

Example

**Pre**

```
modules = ['meta-gnome-core', 'meta-gnome-apps-featured']  # This is what is built by the build slaves (http:build.gnome.org/)
```

**Code**
`modules = ['meta-gnome-core', 'meta-gnome-apps-featured']  # This is what is built by the build slaves (http:build.gnome.org/)`

Comment: I actually want the result to look like **Pre**. But it instead goes off the screen.

Comment: @Tshepang well you will have to choose a different theme to accomodate for the width or set your overflow to auto in the `pre` css in the advanced section, so it displays as above.

Comment: @Tshepang, if an answer helps you, you can vote up the answer.  Click the up arrow to the left of this post.  The description of that action is *This answer is useful*.

Comment: @rchem I wanted to indicate that the Answer didn't help me reach the Answer, but the Comment did. See the Accepted Answer.

Comment: @Tshepang, Alternatively, you could have asked @phwd to edit his comment into the answer and then accepted his answer rather than posting your own.

Comment: @rchem I thought of that and felt like *what the heck, it's no big issue*. Seems to you it's a big issue though. Why?